# Solve $y''(x)^2= (1+y'(x)^2)^n$ where $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How is the familiar ODE solved?

$$y''(x)^2= (1+y'(x)^2)^n$$

Case $n=3$ is known, with two arbitrary constants

$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 =1$$

Substitution $y'(x)= \tan (u)$ is not helping always.

Comment: $z = y’.{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You could try $y'=\sinh(u)$, but for general $n$ this will not simplify much.

Comment: Thanks. Have no special functions ever been constructed ? I ask because the circle case is so well known but the rest are not and there is only a numerical option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution. But at the end one has to use **Chebyshev's theorem on the integration of binomial differentials** to find values of $n$ for which the last equation can integrated.
$$ y''^2 = (1+y'^2)^n \\ \pm y'' = (1+y'^2)^{n/2} \\
 \pm\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{n/2}} = 1 \\
$$
Assume a solution with a derivative that is *not the zero function*, then one can multiply with $y'$
$$
 \pm\frac{y'y''}{(1+y'^2)^{n/2}} = y' \\
 \pm \int \frac{y'y''}{(1+y'^2)^{n/2}}dx = y + c \\
$$
If one sets $z = y'$ it can be easily integrated
$$
\int \frac{zdz}{(1+z^2)^{n/2}} = \frac{\left(z^2+1\right)^{1-\frac{n}{2}}}{2-n}
$$
That means
$$
\pm \frac{\left(y'^2+1\right)^{1-\frac{n}{2}}}{2-n} = y + c\\
\frac{y'^2}{(\mp(2-n)(y + c))^{\frac{2}{2-n}}-1} = 1 \\
\pm\frac{y'}{\sqrt{\left( \mp(2-n)(y + c) \right)^{\frac{2}{2-n}}-1}} = 1
$$
Change variables $y + c = u$ so $dy =du$
$$
\frac{du}{\left(\left( \mp(2-n)u \right)^{\frac{2}{2-n}}-1\right)^{1/2}} = \mp dx
$$
Here I recognize it to be of the form
$$
u^p(a+bu^q)^r du
$$
where $p=0$, $q=\frac{2}{2-n}$ and $r=-\frac{1}{2}$, (also $a = -1$ and $b=(\mp (2-n))^{\frac{2}{2-n}}$). For the integral of such forms see the theorem of **Chebyshev** in [integration of differential binomial](https://www.planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial)

Comment: Ok thanks. And. y(x)=?

Comment: check this, I hope it helps !

Comment: Wow! So even when the three conditions are not satisfied, we have incomplete beta function / Hypergeometric function closed form solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean