# Write a second order DE as a system of first order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

How would I write the following as a system of first order DE:

$xy''+2y'-xy = (x-1)/x^2$

by introducing a new variable $z = y'$

The presence of x as a variable is throwing me off.

Comment: Using $u=xy$ you can write the equation as $u''-u=r(x)$, which you can directly solve or write as a first order system with $v=u'$.

Answer (score 1):

As the right side is not defined for $x=0$, this has to be excluded from the domain. Following that, division by $x$ is permissible without further condition. So
\begin{align}
y'&=z,\\
z'&=\frac{x-1}{x^3}+y-\frac{2z}x,
\end{align}
is a valid first-order system.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy''+2y'-xy = (x-1)/x^2$$
Substitute $y'=z$ and $y''=z"$:
$$xz'+2z=xy+\dfrac {x-1}{x^2}$$
$$z'=-2\dfrac zx+y+\dfrac {x-1}{x^3}$$
And the second DE as:
$$y'=z$$

Note that you can easily solve the second order differential equation since it can be rewritten as:
$$(xy)''-xy=\dfrac {x-1}{x^2}$$

Comment: Where  ? @Physor ...

Comment: If you mean the last line in my answer than it's correct and no $y"$ is missing.

Comment: Oh no problem @Physor

Comment: I think in general $$(xy)^{(n)} = x y^{(n)} + n y^{(n-1)}$$, right ?

Comment: Note that for $n=2$ you have $(xy)''=(y+xy')'=xy''+2y'$ @Physor So I guess your formula is correct at least for $n=2$ I have never seen that formula.

Comment: may I bother you with sth, could you take a look at my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828471/second-order-ode-in-terms-of-n

Comment: This is from the generalized Leibniz rule, $$(uv)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}u^{(k)}v^{(n-k)}.$$ With $u=x$, the sum only has two terms.

Comment: I see I know the Leibniz formula. But i didnt see the link between the two formulas Thanks Lutz @LutzLehmann

Comment: @Physor I saw that answer of yours on the Chebychev's integral nice question and answer.